# Solve for $x$ and $y$ :

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$bx^3 = 10a^2bx + 3a^3y$$
$$ay^3 = 10ab^2y + 3b^3x$$

I tried putting $bx = p$ and $ay = q$ resulting into system of equations:
$$p^3 = 10a^2b^2p + 3a^2b^2q$$
$$q^3 = 10a^2b^2q + 3a^2b^2p$$
Subtracting both I got $$p = q$$ OR $$p^2 + pq + q^2 = 7a^2b^2$$

Putting $p = q$ in cubic equations of $p$ and $q$, I got $p = 0$ or $p = ±√13ab$ implying , $bx = 0$ or $bx = ±√13ab$ i.e., $x = 0$ or $x = ±√13a$ and similarly $y = 0$ or $y = ±√13b$ but there are more values needed to be found. I am not getting how to proceed further. Please help in this direction.

Comment: The solutions depend on $a,b$ and the field involved. For $a=b=0$ all pairs $(x,y)\in K^2$ are solutions. Please say which field $K$ you consider, and which restrictions we have on $a,b\in K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $a,b$ are nonzero. Taking the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of both polynomials in $x$ and $y$, with respect to $x$, we obtain
$$
(13b^2 - y^2)(7b^2 - y^2)(3b + y)(3b - y)(b + y)(b - y)=0.
$$
This yields all nontrivial solutions. Alternatively, you can eliminate $x$ from the second equation, provided that $b\neq 0$ and then substitute this in the first equation. Factoring gives then again the above solutions.

Comment: (+1) would be worth pointing out the algebraic mistakes made by the OP too

Comment: Might be nice way using matrices . What about without using matrices and linear algebra ?

Comment: Isn't there some other way via algebraic manipulation to solve it ?

Comment: Though I didn't understood resultant concept but it gave me motivation enough to solve it . I almost got it and solved the problem fully .

Answer (score 1):

> Subtracting both I got $\;\;p = q\;\;$ OR $\;\;p^2 + pq + q^2 = 7a^2b^2 \tag{1}$

Also, adding both you get $\;\;p = -q\;\;$ OR $\;\;p^2 - pq + q^2 = 13 a^2b^2 \tag{2}$

Subtracting $(1) - (2)$ gives $\;pq = -3a^2b^2\,$, then using $(1)$ gives  $(p+q)^2=7a^2b^2 + pq = 4a^2b^2$. What's left is to solve the quadratics $\,t^2 \pm 2 a b\,t - 3a^2b^2 = 0\,$ for $\,p,q\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ To eliminate the confusion around the special cases $p = \pm q$ here is the complete step-by-step breakdown.

Subtracting and adding the given equations gives the following two equations. That's without any simplifications, so these two equations are completely equivalent to the original system.

$$
\begin{align}
(p-q)(p^2 + pq + q^2) &= 7a^2b^2 \,(p-q) \tag{1'}
\\ (p+q)(p^2 - pq + q^2) &=  13 a^2b^2 \,(p+q) \tag{2'}
\end{align}
$$

At this point, we break down the problem into three cases.

**I.** $\,$ If $p-q = 0$ then $(1')$ is automatically satisfied, and $p = q$ can be determined by substituting into either of the original equations, as the OP has done in the posted question.

**II.** $\,$ If $p+q = 0$ then $(2')$ is automatically satisfied, and $p = -q$ can be determined the same way as in **I**.

**III.** $\,$ If $p-q \ne 0$ *and* $p+q \ne 0$ then the factors $p \pm q$ can be simplified in each equation, which leaves:

$$
\begin{align}
p^2 + pq + q^2 &= 7a^2b^2 \tag{1}
\\ p^2 - pq + q^2 &=  13 a^2b^2 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Case **III.** is the case solved in my answer above. Together with the other two trivial cases **I.** and **II.**, this provides the complete solution set to the original system.

Comment: Nice observation sir 

Comment: But sir can you please make it clear what's variable t here used for ??

Comment: @AshwinBarnwal If you know the sum $p+q = u$ and product $pq = v$ of two numbers, then $p,q$ are the roots $t_{1,2}$ of the associated quadratic $(t-p)(t-q) = 0 = t^2 - u t + v$.

Comment: Sorry but i think you d forgotten that you can only use $$(p-q)(p^2 + pq + q^2) = 7a^2b^2$$ and $$(p+q)(p^2 - pq + q^2) = 13a^2b^2$$ to deduce $$pq = -3a^2b^2$$ when $$(p-q) = (p+q)$$ . So that way , your elimination don't help completely.

Comment: @AshwinBarnwal No, that's not so. First off, the first two equations in your comment are missing factors on the right-hand side of $(p-q)$ and $(p+q)$ respectively. I'll assume those are typos, since you showed in the main post how to deal with the case $p-q=0$. You can deal the same way with the other case $p+q=0$. This leaves the case $p \pm q \ne 0$ to deal with. In that case, you can cancel out the $p \pm q$ factors on both sides of either equation, and you get the two equations labeled $(1)$ and $(2)$ in my answer. You solve those, as shown, and that covers all cases where $p\pm q\ne 0$.

Comment: But it's not necessary that my assumption about p-q = p+q = 0 would be right  . Well i got a point against that elimination 'cause that elimination leads to solution which satisfy one equation but not the other . Check it yourself.

Comment: Well i actually meant it's not necessary that $$p - q$$ and $$p + q$$ will be simultaneously zero 

Comment: @Ash_Blanc You are mistaken. My answer nowhere assumes that $p-q$ and $p+q$ would be *simultaneously* zero. I added a step-by-step breakdown at the end to hopefully clarify the confusion.